# How can I delete a Folder Lock ".flkb" file for which I forgot the password?

Tags: file-permissions

I want to delete a `.flkb` file, which was created through Folder Lock 7 software. This requires a password which I have forgotten. Now this file taking 20 GB space of my drive.

Comment: What do you mean deleting the file requires a password? What happens when you just navigate to that file in your favorite file manager for your favorite OS, and give a "delete" command?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with Folder Lock once. You have two options:

- If you uninstall your Folder Lock then you will be able to delete that file.
- Or alternatively you can download [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/).

After you install Unlocker just right-click on that `.flkb` file and click on Unlocker and then from action select delete and you're done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did you have the same problem with Folder Lock files? Quickly scanning their website, they claim *"Windows kernel level locking and filter driver makes it possible to lock files and folders in Windows Safe Mode"*, which makes me wonder if Unlocker can actually achieve anything there.

Comment: Yes i did and all i did was Use unlocker, don't say I got lucky here ??

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you truly understood the problem. I've never used it. Your answer sounds good then :-)

Comment: Yeah man if you doubt you can try it :)

Comment: Thank you for editing my answer i'm new here so i don't know how to properly format my answer. :)